# Monodevelop 2.2 on OSX - Debugging disabled

Tags: macos, mono, debugging, monodevelop, moonlight

According to the feature matrix of Monodevelop 2.2, debugging should be available on OSX if one installs Mono 2.6.3. I've done this on two of my Macs, but can't seem to get the Debug menuitem enabled - it stays disabled. The project type I'm trying to debug is a Moonlight project, and according to the preferences in Monodevelop, the Moonlight debugger is there and I can even move it to the top as the preferred debugger.

Debugging works for MonoTouch though - so I can in fact debug a C# MonoTouch app.

Anyone know how to enable debugging?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't debug Moonlight/Silverlight projects on OS X.

The SL browser plugin on OS X is the MS Silverlight, not Moonlight, and we don't have access to the MS Silverlight debugging API/protocol.

Comment: Ahh...  Thats a shame.  I thought I finally could get rid of my VM. Don't need for anything but .net development.